# forEach loop in java8 or streams

Tags: java

I was looking to write the below code using Java 8.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
List<EmployeeDetails> emps = getEmployees();
if (emps.size() != 0) {
    for (EmployeeDetails e : emps) {
        employeeList.addAll(convertData(e));
    }
}
```

What would be a good approach? Do I need to use lambda or streams?

Comment: yes, you can use lambdas and streams to do this. If you are interested in learning how, I suggest checking the Oracle tutorials.

Comment: Even if you choose not to use streams, you could consider dropping the `if` statement.  It does nothing here, because if the list is empty, the `for` loop won't iterate.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've written, to be clear, is *just fine,* but if you wanted to rewrite it with streams, it would look like

```
List<Employee> employeeList = getEmployees().stream()
  .flatMap(e -> convertData(e).stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```